# How to Bind json Array to IList Property which is within model? (MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to post back a form using `$.ajax`.  The ajax data will have form data and also have an additional list known as `ItemList`.  I attached the item list array to the serialized form using using `$.extend` (see code below), then stringify the form object before passing it in the ajax post call. 
The controller action is receiving all the data correctly except for the itemList(list of item types) property which is null. I checked if the item object property names match correctly, with `Json` incoming names, which it does. Any Ideas

Target Controller

```
 [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(AddQuoteRequestVM model)
    { 
       .. code here
    }
```

AddQuoteRequestVM

```
    public class AddQuoteRequestVM
    {

         public ParcelVM ItemDescription { get; set; }
           .. other complex type properties
    }
```

ParcelVM

```
 public class ParcelVM
 {
    [Required]
    public IList<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
 }
```

Ajax call

```
   form = jQuery('#createQuoteForm').serializeObject();
   var itemList = $.parseJSON( ko.toJSON(viewModel.ItemList()));

    $.extend(form, { ItemList : itemList});


    var data = JSON.stringify({ model: form });

        $.ajax({
            url: "Add",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model nested in a another model, then it becomes difficult for jquery serializer to map it upto a level. I faced the same issue once.
Try the below workaround and check if the IList object is stilll empty.

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(AddQuoteRequestVM model, IList<Item> ItemList)
    { 
       .. code here
    }
```